# Rotating Views (but not Layouts) on screen orientation change

Tags: android, layout, screen-orientation

I would like to rotate Buttons/TextViews/etc. on screen orientation change but I want to keep layout unchanged. How can it be done? I'm using LinearLayouts.

This is what I mean:
[image: http://i46.tinypic.com/209hwnr.png]

Comment: can create the differnt layout in layout-land and layout-port

Comment: `I would like to rotate Buttons/TextViews/etc. on screen orientation change but I want to keep layout unchanged.` -- do you not see that you're stating `I want to use a new layout but I don't want to use a new layout.`?

Comment: **mah** is it possible without creating new leyout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Create `res->layout->layout-land` and put your xml file for landscape
>   mode

Your layout file in `layout` folder is only for portrait mode Now if you need landscape then  create `layout-land` folder.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done it two ways:

1.) Either you define a new xml file in `layout-land`  folder.

2.) Use `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your activity tag inside manifest.xml

Then in your activity class:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        ChangeToLandscape();
    } else {
        ChangeToPortrait();
    }
}

LayoutParams lp;
public void ChangeToLandscape() {
    lp = new LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView1.setLayoutParams(lp);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); // Whatever you want
    // Similar for other views
}

//Similarly, implement `ChangeToPortrait()`
```

Hope it helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the layout parameters.

Comment: Which parameters? I tried to change layouts orientation to opposite (on screen orientation change) but it didn't work.

Comment: The layout parameters of the layout. It is possible but too much work to do in java. But anyway, check the Samir Mangroliya's answear. It's much better approach.