# How to rotate views on orientation change without recreating layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, android-button, android-orientation

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913248/rotating-views-but-not-layouts-on-screen-orientation-change) but its answer is incorrect. I would like to rotate some views on screen orientation change, but I want to keep the layout unchanged. They should be rotated 90, 180, 270 or 360 degrees according to the current orientation (`SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`, `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`, `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE`, `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT`).

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: LayoutExample]

The answer in the link I mentioned stated that I should create a new different layout in `layout-land`. Clearly, this is not what I want. I don't want to recreate the activity or change layout orientation. I only want to rotate some views, and keep other views unchanged on orientation change.

**There is a huge difference between *rotating* specific views and *changing or recreating* the whole layout (both on orientation change).**

Using the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380989/how-do-i-get-the-current-orientation-activityinfo-screen-orientation-of-an-a), I will be able to get the current screen orientation with this method:

```
public static int getScreenOrientation(Context context) {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int orientation;
    // if the device's natural orientation is portrait:
    if ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) && height > width ||
            (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90
                    || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) && width > height) {
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("ScreenOrientation", "Unknown screen orientation. Defaulting to " + "portrait.");
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
        }
    }
    // if the device's natural orientation is landscape or if the device
    // is square:
    else {
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("ScreenOrientation", "Unknown screen orientation. Defaulting to " + "landscape.");
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
        }
    }

    return orientation;
}
```

On orientation change, I would like to do something simple like this:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, getScreenOrientation(getContext()));
rotateAnimation.setDuration(2000);

for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++) {
    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(i);
    button.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}
```

Another way to rephrase my question would be "Is there any way to detect orientation change in `onConfigurationChanged()` method without changing the layout?". The problem is that it will not be able to detect any orientation change if I already disable layout orientation change.

Anyone knows how it is done? I might have totally gone through wrong steps, and I think I will have to use Accelerometer Sensor or something similar to that to achieve what I want, so please guide me through.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to use `OrientationEventListener`. You don't need to use `onConfigurationChanged` and `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`. 
You need set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for the activity in AndroidManifest.xml. Here is my solution with `OrientationEventListener`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

private ImageButton menuButton;

private Animation toLandAnim, toPortAnim;
private OrientationListener orientationListener;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_image_ruler);

    menuButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
    toLandAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.menubutton_to_landscape);
    toPortAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.menubutton_to_portrait);

    orientationListener = new OrientationListener(this);
}

@Override protected void onStart() {
    orientationListener.enable();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override protected void onStop() {
    orientationListener.disable();
    super.onStop();
}

private class OrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener{
    final int ROTATION_O    = 1;
    final int ROTATION_90   = 2;
    final int ROTATION_180  = 3;
    final int ROTATION_270  = 4;

    private int rotation = 0;
    public OrientationListener(Context context) { super(context); }

    @Override public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        if( (orientation < 35 || orientation > 325) && rotation!= ROTATION_O){ // PORTRAIT
            rotation = ROTATION_O;
            menuButton.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
        }
        else if( orientation > 145 && orientation < 215 && rotation!=ROTATION_180){ // REVERSE PORTRAIT
            rotation = ROTATION_180;
            menuButton.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
        }
        else if(orientation > 55 && orientation < 125 && rotation!=ROTATION_270){ // REVERSE LANDSCAPE
            rotation = ROTATION_270;
            menuButton.startAnimation(toLandAnim);
        }
        else if(orientation > 235 && orientation < 305 && rotation!=ROTATION_90){ //LANDSCAPE
            rotation = ROTATION_90;
            menuButton.startAnimation(toLandAnim);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This also prevents from too frequent rotations when `orientation` is about 45, 135... etc. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. `OrientationEventListener` was what I exactly wanted. I just had to modify some stuff in your code to fulfill my needs.

Comment: However, the system bar and the status bar will be still displayed in portrait mode whatever the orientation of the device. Any solution for that?

Comment: @Fllo The question was about rotating just some views, not whole layout. I'm afraid you have to reload whole layout to landscape/portrait if you want system bars to rotate. You can use: `setRequestedOrientation(requestedRotation)` in `OrientationListener .onOrientationChanged` or much easier set `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` in AndroidManifest.xml for your Activity

Comment: @mirekkomis No problem, I found [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42612813/2668136) - last part of the answer linked.

Comment: After a loooong search, finally a worthy answer.

Answer (score 1):

The basics are actually a lot easier. Have a look at [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).

First things first, by setting

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

in your Manifest on your activity tag you can handle the orientation change yourself. (`orientation` should be enough, but there are sometimes issues where the event does not fire with that alone.)

You then skip `onCreate` and instead `onConfigurationChanged` gets called. Overwrite this method and apply your layout changes here. Whether you change your linearLayouts orientation here or have a custom view handling layout for different screens itself is up to you and depends on your implementation.

Animating will be a bit trickier, if it is even possilbe. A quick search says [it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957772/disable-default-animation-from-portrait-to-landscape).

---

**Update** for comment "I only want to rotate some views themselves rather than rotating the layout"

*In theory* it is possible to create your own layout and handle the drawing of your child views. I just tried it but could not produce any results in an appropriate time, but what you would need to do:

- **keep your last measured values** use tags on the view or similar approaches to keep the last measurements and layouts, so that after the orientation change you can diff
- **await orientation change**: trigger *rotated drawing* - rotate the canvas, layout the views with the **previous** dimensions, and draw the child views where they would have been *before*, and
- **start an animation** interpolate from the *last* to the *new* values, rotating the canvas from the last to the new layout

This is how I would do it.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, but I have already tried that, and the problem still persists. Although the orientation change will be detected and I can rotate the views I want through it, the layout will still be rotated on orientation change, and I only want to rotate some views themselves rather than rotating the layout. Is there any way to detect orientation change without changing the layout?

Comment: @HusseinElFeky I think you need to go into more detail. Basically "just rotating the views and not the layout" would require you to write a custom layout and there you could react to the change and then rotate/move your views accordingly...I'll just quickly try that

Comment: @HusseinElFeky I wasn't successful but updated the answer to include the idea

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the problem is that my layout is quite complex, and I'm actually using ViewPager with 10 fragments (pages). I know that's a lot, so if I did as what you said, it would take a bunch of time to reload the whole activity again and would consume a lot of memory (I have already tested it). That's why I'm looking for an answer that doesn't require changing layouts. Thanks for your help though.